# Pass values to string after iterating over array

Tags: python

I have and array with nested objects that i want to iterate through and pass the values to a string. I also want to concat the values with another string, as in the example. Im used to JavaScript and i know that this can be done with a map method there. But i'm struggling to find an equivalent in Python.

So my goal is to dynamically pass the values to the string after iterating the array.

```py
objExpression = [
   {
      'name': 'name',
      'value': id,
      'type': 'S',   
   },
   {
      'name': 'brandCode',
      'value': brandCode,
      'type': 'S',   
   },
   ...
]

 UpdateExpression='SET #'+objExpression[0]['name']+'= :'objExpression[0]['name']+',' '#'+objExpression[1]['name']+'= :'+objExpression[2]['name'] ...'

#Expected output

UpdateExpression='SET #name = :name, #brandCode = :brandCode'
```

Comment: Your last line is very unclear: there's `['name']` every time, but twice for index 0, and once for index 1 and once for index 2. Please show the expected output, that'll be far easier.

Comment: Python has a `map` function, but often, things can be done without it as well, and it may be clearer (or just as clear).

Comment: Your expected output shows `#name = :name` and the same for 'brandCode': is that really what you want?

Comment: @9769953 Yes, its a dynamodb expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
"SET "  + ", ".join(f"#{item['name']} = :{item['name']}" for item in objExpression)
```

which gives

```
'SET #name = :name, #brandCode = :brandCode'
```

The above futures:

- a list comprehension: `[item for item in objExpression]`.
- an f-string: `f"#{item} = :{item}"`
- an f-string with a dict lookup: `f"#{item['name']}"`  (*)
- a string concatenation with `", ".join(list_of_strings)`.

Note: the list_of_strings looks like it's missing its square brackets, `[]`, from the first bullet point. I have turned it into a generator expression, marked by the `()`, which you can do for some cases. In this cases, the `()` actually mark the method call of `join()`, where you can fit a generator expression inside of. The result is an iterable of strings, which works fine for `.join()`.

(*) You can put lengthy expressions inside an f-string; just don't do it for clarity. A key lookup is already a tad confusing, with single quotes for the keys and double quotes as the string delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
objExpression = [
   {
      'name': 'name',
      'value': 1,
      'type': 'S',   
   },
   {
      'name': 'brandCode',
      'value': 123,
      'type': 'S',   
   }
]

UpdateExpression = 'SET '
tmpExpression = []
for exp in objExpression:
    tmpExpression.append(f"#{exp['name']} = :{exp['name']}")

UpdateExpression += ', '.join(tmpExpression)
```

The output:

```
'SET #name = :name, #brandCode = :brandCode'
```

Comment: Note that for long (final) strings and/or long loops, `.join()` is often preferred. I think it might be faster and use less memory.

Comment: `.join()` also avoids the trailing comma problem.

Comment: Yes, I have just realized after I see your answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop Through your array and add your values just like the below code

```
string = 'SET '
for dicts in objExpression:
  string += f"#{dicts['name']} = :{dicts['name']} ,"
```

the output is:

```
SET #name = :name ,#brandCode = :brandCode ,
```